# defining a custom type in Go

Tags: go

I am trying to define a custom type that returns a random number and use that type in a struct but I can't seem to get it right. Here is what I am doing

```
type genRandFunc func() int 

func genRand() genRandFunc{
    return func() int {
        return rand.Intn(1000)
    }
}

type User struct {
    parseID  genRand()
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Your `User` type definition is wrong. `getRand()` is a function call, not a type. Use

```
type User struct {
  parseID genRandFunc
}

...
x:=User{parseID: getRand()}
```

Comment: THis is returning an error - https://play.golang.org/p/DOfyuBawADv

Comment: @shekwo you can't define functions like that inside a function. Try Burak's answer like this https://play.golang.org/p/Ap3KFd7GeVQ

Comment: You have to fix the syntax: https://play.golang.org/p/YF578vtPUj5